# VS 2015 Publish is failing -

Tags: c#

Hi My WEB API project is failing with these error.

Though I could build and run my project without any error.

> 2>        CopyPipelineFiles: Copying build\native\bin\$(NativeDependenciesToolset)\$(NativeDependenciesPlatform)\$(NativeDependenciesConfiguration)\dynamic\$(ZlibCallingConvention)\zlib.dll to C:\Temp\Package\PackageTmp\build\native\bin\$(NativeDependenciesToolset)\$(NativeDependenciesPlatform)\$(NativeDependenciesConfiguration)\dynamic\$(ZlibCallingConvention)\zlib.dll.
>
> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2991,5): 
>       Error : Copying file build\native\bin\$(NativeDependenciesToolset)\$(NativeDependenciesPlatform)\$(NativeDependenciesConfiguration)\dynamic\$(ZlibCallingConvention)\zlib.dll to C:\Temp\Package\PackageTmp\build\native\bin\$(NativeDependenciesToolset)\$(NativeDependenciesPlatform)\$(NativeDependenciesConfiguration)\dynamic\$(ZlibCallingConvention)\zlib.dll failed. Could not find file 'build\native\bin\$(NativeDependenciesToolset)\$(NativeDependenciesPlatform)\$(NativeDependenciesConfiguration)\dynamic\

Comment: Im no doctor, but have you checked the path for 'zlib.dll'. Just because it runs locally does not mean the file is there, it could be in you GDC.

Comment: For ZLib.dll when you right click "File Properties" what have you got for "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it turns out to be a 264 character limit. After making a Subst to the folder source solution published correctly.